# Nested list missing after read from file

Tags: python, list, file, nested

So, i have a nested list written into a file.txt

```
students = []
info = []
name = input("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")
info.append(name)
info.append(age)
students.append(info)
my_file = open("file.txt", "a")
for data in students:
    my_file.write("%s\n" % data)
my_file.close()
```

The contents in the file are in this format: 
['john', '19']
['nick', '20']

Afterwards, i'm using nested loop to access the content of file.txt

```
 my_file = open("file.txt", "r")
 search_keyword = input("Please Enter Student Name: ")
    for students in my_file:
        for info in students:
            print(info)
```

Expected output:

```
john
19
nick
20
```

Actual output:

```
j
o
h
n
1
9
n
i
c
k
2
0
```

Can someone explain why the inner list is missing after extracting from a file, as the loop treats each individual alphabet as an element.

Comment: To save your data i'd recommend using csv format that way you can use the built in `csv` package to easily parse your file. Saving the data with brackets and quotation marks just makes it harder to read and parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, I'm not 100% sure but maybe try: `my_file.writelines("")`

Answer (score 0):

This seems a good candidate for [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) since you have a Python data structure you want to preserve.

```
import pickle

lol = [['john', '19'],['nick', '20']]

with open('lol.pickle','wb') as f: 
    pickle.dump(lol,f)

del lol
print(lol)
# NameError: name 'lol' is not defined

with open('lol.pickle','rb') as f: 
    lol = pickle.load(f) 

print(lol)
# [['john', '19'], ['nick', '20']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your precious time, but i'm actually working on a beginner project, where we are not suppose to import other module to assist our work.

Comment: @Wesley: aha! Well, that makes a lot of sense for a beginning project. Cheers, and happy coding to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have read the data as a string, so when you iterate you are iterating through elements of a string, not elements of a list.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are learning python. The current program works, but is not the best way to do it. You should try using `csv` or `pickle`. However, it is always good to start from basic! :D

```
students = []
info = []

name = input("Name: ")
age = input("Age: ")

info.append(name)
info.append(age)

students.append(info)

with open("file.txt", "a") as my_file:
    for data in students:
        my_file.write("%s,%s\n" % (data[0], data[1])) # this will write in file like name,age
```

After that you can retrieve like

```
search_keyword = input("Please Enter Student Name: ")
with open("file.txt", "r") as my_file:
   for students in my_file:
       for info in students.split(','): # We split it based on commas to get the desired output
           print(info)
```

The mistake you were making is that when you tried `for info in students` you were iterating over characters in the string rather than the actual information.

Notice how we have used `with open` this will do all the file handling automatically.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, it worked! I'm actually trying to implement a search feature, hence there is a need to preserve the list, and access the element of list (such as name & age) by calling the list's index (info[0]). Can i know how can i alternate this can make it work?

Comment: You can do that in json, csv, pickle or anything similar. Those modules are specifically designed for storing something in file and retrieving them. They offer more robustness and ease to program with it.

Comment: Why aren't you using the csv module to read and write to the csv file?

Comment: Are there any alternatives to work around this tho? Because we aren't actually allowed to import external modules sadly :(

Comment: If you are not supposed to use modules then maybe yeah... that's the way you have to go about it..

Answer (score 0):

[Iterating over file-like objects produces lines](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
for students in my_file:
```

On each iteration `students` will be a line of text.

Iterating over text produces individual characters.

```
for info in students:
```

On each iteration `info` will be a character.

If your text files have string representations of python objects you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to evaluate the objects.

```
import ast
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        thing = ast.literal_eval(line)
        print(thing)
        for item in thing:
            print(item)
```

As mentioned in the docs, `ast.literal_eval` `Safely evaluate an expression node or a string` with emphasis on **safe** - it shouldn't evaluate *destructive* or unwanted Python statements.

---

You would be better off using one of the built-in [data persistence modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html) or perhaps [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or even [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/markup.html) to save your data.